# problems with Ocaml in int list list

Tags: ocaml

How can I add an element into a int list list?

```
    |x::y::xs->  if(x<=y)                                                           
                 then [x]@(ordina (y::xs))
                 else [x]::ordina (y::xs)
```

I tried with this, but it didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

To add a new int list containing `x` to the head of an `int list list`:

```
# let x = 14 in
let ill = [[3;4]; [5;6]] in
[x] :: ill ;;
- : int list list = [[14]; [3; 4]; [5; 6]]
```

You can also write this:

```
# let x = 14 in
let ill = [[3;4]; [5;6]] in
[[x]] @ ill ;;
- : int list list = [[14]; [3; 4]; [5; 6]]
```

But this entails a tiny amount of unnecessary work.

As a side comment, the two branches of your `if` look like they're trying to do the same thing. If you want the result to be `[[14; 3; 4]; [5; 6]]` you need to write a little more code to destructure the `int list list`.

```
# let x = 14 in
let ill = [[3;4]; [5;6]] in
match ill with
| [] -> [[x]]
| h :: t -> (x :: h) :: t ;;
- : int list list = [[14; 3; 4]; [5; 6]]
```